# What are the implications of framing a classification problem against classes conceived as DAG vs DAG-SS?

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification

Imagine a problem where one needs to characterize documents within a hierarchy of classes.  I'll use the simple animal example where a document may fit "dog" or "cat" or "chicken" or "ostrich".  OR the document may best fit a parent category such as "mammals" vs "birds."  It seems to me one could go about such a problem by starting at the top of the decision tree and moving it as far towards the leaf nodes as you find evidence that you can, in fact, make a meaningful discrimination.  For sake of simplicity, I'm imagining a single class label per document.  For example, you may have a document that mentions dog and cat terminology in sufficient measure such that you can't classify it as dogs or cats in particular and my best assign the single class of "mammals".

While I'm expecting this to be challenging given my domain and the surrounding terminology has (intuitively) a lot of overlap in the child classes, **I'm somewhat fearful that a set of classes *without* the strict hierarchy would be much more challenging**.  At least with the hierarchy, you would have a deterministic path of decisions, whereas a set of classes with more of a DAG structure (as opposed to DAG-SS), seems more or less intractable.

My intuition tells me that we should represent orthogonal concepts as disjoint hierarchies.  I'm also concerned that the inherent predictive power the contents of the documents may often result in a situation where most labels don't end up descending very far down the hierarchy.  For example, the model may say "We're highly confident that it's about 'mammals' but we can't say that it's specifically meant to address cats vs dogs.  I can imagine that documents may mention *examples* of mammals, *but* if they only serve as examples then the document is truly only about mammals... not the examples.

I'm grateful for any words of wisdom from the trenches.  I've not ventured very far down the path of exploration, and therefore I'm very interested to hear from those who may have hands-on experience with such matters.